# Postgresqlにて指定した範囲の時間を含まないデータを取得したい

Tags: postgresql

いつもお世話になっております。

早速本題ですが、
スケジュールといったEntityが存在し、その中に睡眠開始時刻と起床時刻(SleepStartTime/SleepEndTime)が保存されています。

このとき、睡眠時間が1:00~4:00の時間帯に重複しないレコードを取得しようとしているのですが、
中々うまく行きません。
(not inを使うのかなとは思いいろいろとチャレンジはしているのですが...)

データベースはpostgresqlになります。

以下のイメージになります。(一部抜き出し)
ScheduleEntity
id  : longintger
SleepStart :time
SleepEnd : time

取得したいテーブル例
id: 1 SleepStart:23:00 SleepEnd:0:30
id: 2 SleepStart:05:00 SleepEnd:12:30

取得したくないテーブル例
id: 3 SleepStart:00:00 SleepEnd:03:30
id: 4 SleepStart:02:00 SleepEnd:08:30
id: 5 SleepStart:00:30 SleepEnd:09:30

お手数ですが、わかる方教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: (1:00 <= SleepStart and SleepStart <= 4:00) or (1:00 <= SleepEnd and SleepEnd <= 4:00) のような条件ではダメなんですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL には overlaps がありますので、

```
select * from ScheduleEntity where not (SleepStart, SleepEnd) overlaps (time '1:00', time '4:00');
```

とすれば良いはず、、、なのですが、`id:1` の SleepEnd が `0:30` となっていますので抽出できません。

そこで、`SleepStart > SleepEnd` の場合は start と end を逆転して overlap を検査します。この場合は起きている時間になるので `where (SleepStart, SleepEnd) overlaps ...` になります。

```sql
create table ScheduleEntity (
  id int,
  SleepStart time,
  SleepEnd time,
  primary key (id)
);

insert into ScheduleEntity(id, SleepStart, SleepEnd) values (1, '23:00', '0:30');
insert into ScheduleEntity(id, SleepStart, SleepEnd) values (2, '5:00', '12:30');
insert into ScheduleEntity(id, SleepStart, SleepEnd) values (3, '0:00', '3:30');
insert into ScheduleEntity(id, SleepStart, SleepEnd) values (4, '2:00', '8:30');
insert into ScheduleEntity(id, SleepStart, SleepEnd) values (5, '0:30', '9:30');
insert into ScheduleEntity(id, SleepStart, SleepEnd) values (6, '22:00', '4:30');

select * from ScheduleEntity
where
  (SleepStart > SleepEnd and (SleepEnd, SleepStart) overlaps (time '1:00', time '4:00'))
or
  (SleepStart <= SleepEnd and not (SleepStart, SleepEnd) overlaps (time '1:00', time '4:00'));

 id | sleepstart | sleepend 
----+------------+----------
  1 | 23:00:00   | 00:30:00
  2 | 05:00:00   | 12:30:00
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。非常に助かりました！！